How can I store proxy user password securely using proxy_override in Oracle APEX_WEB_SERVICE.MAKE_REST_REQUEST?
I call an external HTTP API endpoint from the inside our comapny's network. I use Oracle's function:
apex_web_service.make_rest_request
    (p_url => l_url
    ,p_http_method       => 'POST'
    ,p_body              => request_body_v
    ,p_transfer_timeout  => 10
    ,p_proxy_override    => 'my-domain\my-user:my-password@proxy.my-domain.local');

How can I store my-user and my-password scurely (used in p_proxy_override) and refer to them in p_proxy_override parameter?
Want to avoid to put it in clear text.
If I use 'my-domain\my-user:my-password@proxy.my-domain.local' in clear text then I get response but this unacceptable for security reasons
Where/how can I store these credentials and then refer to them in the p_proxy_parameter?
